# Why the browser is not downloading the file set in the html anchor tag href?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to create a portfolio site in react. Within it, I have set an anchor tag where a user can download the resume if he would need it. But the problem is actually weird. The path to the file is right and I have also set the download attribute on the `<a>` tag.

The problem is When I write the path to the file in the `<a>` tag `href`, neither the IDM nor the browser was downloading the file. But when I import it and use that import in the `<a>` tag then IDM is downloading the file but the browser isn't. Although my primary concern is to download the file in the browser. But I am also wondering about the logic behind why the browser is not downloading the file when IDM is downloading it?
Also looking forward to the solution:  why the file is not downloading in the browser?

Thanks :)

Here is my anchor tag code :

```
<a href={Resume} target="_blank" className="button" download>
       <i className="fa fa-download"></i>Download Resume
</a>
```

**Note:** the browser is displaying the file name and  the type of the file but not downloading it and giving the error ("Failed- No File")

Comment: Probably `target="_blank"`; you don't need that if you have `download`.

Comment: Seems like it can't find your file. Can you open your page in a browser and then copy the link (the evaluated value of the `href` property) and paste it in a new tab? I'd guess that this gives you an error 404 (And it might help to comment the value of it here)